# Would it be possible to print the file used to redirect STDERR?

Tags: shell, aix

Would it be possible to print the filename used to redirect STDERR, given the sample command below:

```
command.sh 2>file.err
```

Code in command.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -l non_existing_file.txt
echo "STDERR file is: $stderrFilename" # variable should print file.err
```

Comment: See the `lsof` command; you are looking for the file associated with file descriptor 2 of the current process.

Comment: Thanks but lsof isn't installed.

Comment: (Is there an actual reason for this, or just an academical question?)

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, Both academical and has an actual reason. I have a generic script that reads files which anyone can use but the stderr filename can be up to them to decide. The filenames will be appended to a log file. Hope my intentions are clear enough :)

Comment: What use of such log-file would have? Say, you have lots of entries like `/dev/pts/3` and `/tmp/err.172923` and `/home/joe/check-and-remove.log` then  what you plan to do with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a solution using history. Not sure if there is an easier way to do this ( or a proper one).

```
#!/bin/sh
stderrfname=`history | tail -1 | awk '{ print $3 }' | sed "s/.*>//"`
echo "STDERR file is: $stderrfname"
```

Comment: Gonna use this for now.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little risky, but you could try parsing AIX's [procfiles](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/procfiles.htm) output. It involves capturing the major and minor numbers of the stderr device, along with the inode number, then looking for the corresponding device, its mountpoint, and then using `find` to look for the file with the given inode number:

```
#!/bin/sh
dev=$(procfiles $$ | awk '$1 == "2:" { print substr($4, 5) }')
inode=$(procfiles $$ | awk '$1 == "2:" { print substr($5, 5) }')

major=${dev%%,*}
minor=${dev##*,}

if [ "$major}" -eq 0 ]
then
  echo I give up, the major number is zero
  exit 1
fi

for file in /dev/*
do
  [ -b "$file" ] || continue
  if istat "$file" | grep -q "^Major Device ${major}.*Minor Device ${minor}$"
  then
    break
  fi
done

fs=$(mount | awk '$1 == "'"${file}"'" { print $2 }')
stderrFilename=$(find "$fs" -inum "$inode")
```

Comment: I will try to get on this.